# Check the list of websites for a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, web-scraping

I have a list of URL's (websites) that I want to scan if they use a certain Wordpress Plugin or not. On one of the communities I was recommended the following tip:

```
"for link in `cat links`; do wget -O link $link/wp-content/plugins/megaplugin/name.php -nv; done"
```

Can someone say where do I enter/run this code? Or maybe give an extended explanation about my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in a shell terminal on Apple's OS X or Linux.

You are using a couple command line shell binaries:

- `cat`
- `wget`

The rest are scripting commands:

- `for`
- `do`
- `done`

. [Here is a shell scripting guide.](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_01_01.html)

The text file will needs to be named `links` if you don't want to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have two option in my opinion:
1.first one is what you mentioned yourself! it's something like link validation that you should check that if is www.website.com/wp-content/plugins/megaplugin/name.php is a valid link or not.
but I haven't done this way before myself.

2.second way is to parse HTML of those website that you want to check them for any sign of that specific plugin in it's HTML codes, even in it's comment codes! for example if you see the website that it's seo plugin is yoast seo wordpress plugin, in the HTML code you can find some comment parts that says that this website is using this plugin.
and of course this way is just good for those plugins that have any kind of signs from them in website' HTML codes!